# Debugging Boost Serialization segfault issue

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, segmentation-fault

Running this C++ code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  try {

    stringstream ss;

    {
      boost::archive::text_oarchive oa( ss );
      oa << "test"; // <- segfaults here
    }

    cout << ss.str() << endl;

  }
  catch ( exception& ex ) {

    cerr << ex.what() << endl;

  }

  return 0;

} // main
```

On one system (cherry) it runs with no problem:

```
[jj5@cherry SerializationTest]$ make && catchsegv dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest 
"make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jj5/code/SerializationTest'
"make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jj5/code/SerializationTest'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  -pthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system -lboost_serialization -Wl,-Bdynamic
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jj5/code/SerializationTest'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jj5/code/SerializationTest'
22 serialization::archive 13 5 116 101 115 116 0
```

On another system (orac) it segfaults at runtime:

```
[jj5@orac SerializationTest]$ make && catchsegv ./dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest 
"make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/jj5/repo/svn/code/SerializationTest'
"make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/jj5/repo/svn/code/SerializationTest'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/serializationtest build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  -pthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system -lboost_serialization -Wl,-Bdynamic
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jj5/repo/svn/code/SerializationTest'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jj5/repo/svn/code/SerializationTest'
Segmentation fault
*** Segmentation fault
Register dump:

 RAX: 0000000000000018   RBX: 00007ffc55f07fb8   RCX: 00007ffc55f07ea8
 RDX: 0000000000000000   RSI: 00007ffc55f08018   RDI: 00007ffc55f07e80
 RBP: 00007ffc55f07fe0   R8 : 00007ffc55f07ea8   R9 : 00007ffc55f07bc0
 R10: 00007ffc55f07ad0   R11: 00007fedf16a03c0   R12: 00007ffc55f08018
 R13: 00007ffc55f08230   R14: 0000000000000000   R15: 0000000000000000
 RSP: 00007ffc55f07e78

 RIP: 00007fedf1c13860   EFLAGS: 00010206

 CS: 0033   FS: 0000   GS: 0000

 Trap: 0000000e   Error: 00000006   OldMask: 00000000   CR2: 00000018

 FPUCW: 0000037f   FPUSW: 00000000   TAG: 00000000
 RIP: 00000000   RDP: 00000000

 ST(0) 0000 0000000000000000   ST(1) 0000 0000000000000000
 ST(2) 0000 0000000000000000   ST(3) 0000 0000000000000000
 ST(4) 0000 0000000000000000   ST(5) 0000 0000000000000000
 ST(6) 0000 0000000000000000   ST(7) 0000 0000000000000000
 mxcsr: 1f80
 XMM0:  00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM1:  00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM2:  00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM3:  00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM4:  00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM5:  00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM6:  00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM7:  00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM8:  00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM9:  00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM10: 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM11: 00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM12: 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM13: 00000000000000000000000000000000
 XMM14: 00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM15: 00000000000000000000000000000000

Backtrace:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt6localeC1ERKS_+0x10)[0x7fedf1c13860]
??:?(_ZN5boost7archive28basic_streambuf_locale_saverIcSt11char_traitsIcEED1Ev)[0x40721e]
??:?(_ZN5boost7archive21basic_text_oprimitiveISoED1Ev)[0x4073e3]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:97 (discriminator 2)(_ZN5boost7archive18text_oarchive_implINS0_13text_oarchiveEED2Ev)[0x402b3a]
/usr/local/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:114(_ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveD2Ev)[0x402aaf]
/home/jj5/repo/svn/code/SerializationTest/main.cpp:23(main)[0x402686]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fedf10e8b45]
??:?(_start)[0x4024ca]
```

Any idea how I can fix the issue on the second system Orac? In both cases the libraries are statically linked so I don't understand why there is a runtime error and not a compile time error. Perhaps there is an issue with the Boost installation on Orac?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to old boost libraries. I found the outdated libraries like this:

```
root@orac:/home/jj5# find /usr -iname '*boost*' | sort | less
```

I removed them like this:

```
root@orac:/home/jj5# cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
root@orac:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# rm -rf libboost_*
root@orac:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# cd /usr/local/lib
root@orac:/usr/local/lib# rm -rf libboost_*.1.58.0
```